Spring Boot JdbcUserDetailsManager can't create tables and insert
I'm trying to make an application with spring security and the JdbcUserDetailsManager
When I start the spring boot application I get an error message:
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into users (username, password, enabled) values (?,?,?)]

I thought this is cause there is no table 'users', although the JdbcUserDetailsManager should create it on its own.
I did create the tables on manually and still the error persists.
Any Idea What could be the cause?
@Configuration
public class UserDetailsConfig {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    UserDetailsManager users(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println();
        UserDetails defaultUser = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(this.passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .build();
        JdbcUserDetailsManager users = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        try {
            //users.deleteUser(defaultUser.getUsername());
            users.createUser(defaultUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("database not yet initialized");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return users;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/food_production
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

server.port=6969

spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin
spring.security.user.roles=admin

spring version: 3.2.2
Java version 17
Postgresql version 16.2

What makes you think the JdbcUserDetailsManager should create its own tables, because it doesn't. Spring Security does ship with create scripts which you can execute but it won't do that itself.

Ok, so I found that what M. Deinum sad is true, there are these ddls, but I tried to create the database with the ddl script, but varchar_ignorecase() does not exist in postgres so you have to remove the _ignorecase then itworks;
Solution:
remove _ignorecase from the spring suggested script when initializing the database
